# divide one table data from other table data using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I had tried to display the divided value of **saleprice** from the table **(additem)** and from the table **(addbill)** data .i.e.quantity that we entered in the **addbill** table and display the value in the price column in **addbill** table.

Previously I was done to fetch from one table data from other table data

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
  $m = $_POST['itemname'];
  $sp = "SELECT saleprice FROM additem WHERE itemname='$m'";
  $q = mysqli_query($link,$sp);
  $n = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
  $saleprice = $n['saleprice'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO addbill (bill_id,itemname,quantity,price) VALUES 
 ('".$_POST['billid']."','".$_POST['itemname']."','".$_POST['quantity']."','" .$saleprice."')";
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
  if ($result) {
    header("Location:addbill.php");
  }else{
    echo "error during adding";
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code broken?  Why are you using `mysql_` functions?  Do you have a working db connection?  What outcome are you getting?  Your query is insecure and unstable because you are not using prepared statements.  You can use a subquery to SELECT inside of your INSERT.

Comment: ditto. `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dinner']);` should be `mysqli_real_escape_string($link ,$_POST['dinner']);`

Comment: I don't see any division attempted in your snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am not sure why you are using MySQL and mysqli both together, but for your concern, you have to calculate the new sale price before inserting records in database & then insert the calculated sale price instead of an original sale price.

```
$intSalesPrice = $saleprice * $_POST['quantity'];
```

You can calculate new sales prices like this.